# Segmentation fault with a linked stack trying to evaluate postfix expressions

Tags: c, linked-list, stack, postfix-notation

I am attempting to implement a linked stack to evaluate post fix expressions however I keep getting a segmentation fault and not sure how to go about fixing it. I'm new to c programming which is different from OOD so any advice is welcomed. Thank you & please excuse my comments and spacing.

```
 #include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct node {
int data;
struct node *next;
};
 struct node *top = NULL;


void push(int data);
int pop();
int evaluatePostfix(char* exp);

void main() {
     char postfixExp[256];

     printf("What is your Postfix Expression? : \n");

     fgets(postfixExp, sizeof(postfixExp), stdin);
     printf("%d\n", evaluatePostfix(postfixExp));
}

//done
void push(int data) {
     struct node *newNode;
     newNode = (struct node*)malloc(sizeof(struct node));;
     (*newNode).data = data;
     (*newNode).next = NULL;
     //use isEmpty if can
     if (top != NULL) {
         (*newNode).next = top;
     }
     top = newNode;
}
//done
int pop() {
    struct node *temp = top;
    int *remove;
    //use isEmpty if can
    if (top != NULL) {
        *remove = (*top).data;
        top = (*top).next;
        free(temp);
    }
return *remove;

}

 int evaluatePostfix(char* exp) {
     struct node *top = NULL;
     for (int i = 0; i < sizeof(exp); i++) {
      if (isdigit(exp[i])) {
        push(exp[i]);
    } else {
        int val1 = pop();
        int val2 = pop();
        switch(exp[i]) {
            case '+':
                push(val2+val1);
                break;
            case '-':
                push(val2-val1);
                break;
            case '*':
                push(val2*val1);
                break;
            case '/':
                push(val2/val1);
                break;
        }
    }
}
return pop();

}
```

Comment: `(*newNode).data` is syntax-sugared with `newNode->data`

Comment: `*remove = (*top).data;` BZZZ! dereferencing an invalid pointer (`remove`).

Comment: Should be `int result=0;` `result = top->data;` and `return result;`

Answer (score 0):

I have fully undestood your error the error in value is attributed to many factors

> 1. pointed out by @Eugene Sh. `int remove` change it data type to integer
> 2. the loop you are iterating is twice the size of expression since you are using constant literal you should use `for (int i = 0; i < strlen(exp)-1; i++)` subtracting `1` because of `\0`
> 3. what you are doing here is

```
   if (isdigit(exp[i])) {
    push(exp[i]);
} else {
    int val1 = pop();
    int val2 = pop();
```

since `34+` be an expression then you checked using `isdigit(exp[i])`

> **isdigit(exp[i])** only check the passed character is a decimal digit character.

subtract `(exp[i])` with `48` ascii value of `0` to convert decimal ascii character to integer

modify your code like this

> 1. 

```
 int pop() {
struct node *temp = top;
int removed;
//use isEmpty if can
if (top != NULL) {
    removed = (*top).data;
    top = (*top).next;
    free(temp);
 }
 return removed;
}
```

> 2&3.

```
for (int i = 0; i < strlen(exp)-1; i++) {
  if (isdigit(exp[i])) {
    push(exp[i]-48);
} else {
    int val1 = pop();
    int val2 = pop();
printf("val1%d\n",val1);
printf("val2%d\n",val2);
```

your working code
    http://ideone.com/z58Phy